# How to pass context to a Ruby method defined in C/C++

Tags: ruby, wrapper

I am currently writing a set of API bindings to the Ruby interpreter. The problem is that the binding definitions are not static and retrieved on initialization. I can easily create types on the fly, but in order to add methods I need static handlers:

```
static VALUE dispatchInstanceMethod( int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE obj )
{...}

static VALUE dispatchClassMethod( int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE obj )
{...}

VALUE cls  = rb_define_class_id_under( myModule, nameID, rb_cObject );
rb_define_method( cls, "methodName", RUBY_METHOD_FUNC(dispatchInstanceMethod), -1 );
rb_define_singleton_method( cls, "methodName", RUBY_METHOD_FUNC(dispatchClassMethod), -1 );
```

However, this requires each method (both static and instance methods) to use different handlers.
Since I am generating these definitions on the runtime, I must use a generic dispatcher to
deal with all method calls. However, my dispatcher cannot know which method and of which class
was called. How can I retrieve that information? The class info could be retrieved
from the `self` object passed to the handler, but in case of static method the `self` is the
type itself. Can I attach any sort of user data to the Class type `VALUE`? And how can I know
which Ruby method was called if each method uses the same dispatcher function?

A few other interpreters I have worked against in the past have provided a
generic `void*` pointer for this kind of data (usually along with the release function), or some other mechanism, but there doesn't seem to be anything like that in Ruby. Have I missed it, or is such use simply not available?

Comment: What do you mean that the definitions are "retrieved on initialization"? Assuming you had your generic dispatch function, what would your calls to the definitions look like?

Comment: @Max The definitions of available classes and their APIs are retrieved over a TCP connection. My generic handler simply serializes the input arguments, attaches the class, object(if not static) and method ID and sends the data to the remote server which completes the call. Then it waits for a response and de-serializes it and returns to the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little more experimental. I'm not sure exactly how this will work, but it's based on Ruby's [define_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-define_method) for defining proper methods at runtime

```c
VALUE context; // context for method call

VALUE dispatchInstanceMethod(VALUE first_arg, VALUE context, int argc, VALUE* argv)
{
    // first_arg is the first arg passed to your method, probably shouldn't use it
    // just use argc, argv instead for accessing all args
    // context should(?) be what we passed at the time of definition
}

void dynamically_create_class()
{
    VALUE cls = rb_define_class_id_under(myModule, nameID, rb_cObject);
    ID define_method = rb_intern("define_method");

    VALUE name = // method name as a Symbol object e.g. using ID2SYM
    context = // set to whatever context we need for the call
    rb_global_variable(context); // don't garbage-collect it
    rb_block_call(cls, define_method, 1, &name, dispatchInstanceMethod, context);
}
```

For this to work (if it can work), you'd need a different `context` variable for each method definition. The lifetime of these variables would have to exceed the life of the class, thus they'd need to be globally available somewhere. That's how you would differentiate `dispatchInstanceMethod` later on when it actually gets called by each method.

Comment: I found it the most useful approach as it is contained entirely on the C++ side (for me it is a plus) and uses Ruby mechanics for function dispatching - therefore API registered this way (unlike using `method_missing`) is discoverable using `.methods`.

Comment: For other who may be wondering: it took me a moment to find the `self` pointer in the method implementation. It is `rb_current_receiver()`

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you from doing this the normal Ruby way, by defining [method_missing](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing). That gives you a generic dispatcher. In Ruby it looks like this

```
class Foo
  def self.method_missing symbol, args
    # dispatch class method
  end

  def method_missing symbol, args
    # dispatch instance method
  end
end
```

In the C API you do this normal way, using `rb_define_method` and `rb_define_singleton_method`. I haven't tested it, but I imagine you can even pass the same handler to both and use the value of `self` to determine which dispatch (class/instance) to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing that's *way* easier to do in normal Ruby. I would write a C API method for making a generic API call using basic types (i.e. no custom classes). For example, something like

```
VALUE api_call(VALUE self, VALUE class_name, VALUE method_name, VALUE instance_variables, VALUE arguments)
{
    // turn class_name, method_name, instance_variables, arguments into an API call
}

mAPI = rb_define_module("MyAPI");
rb_define_singleton_method(mAPI, "call", api_call, 4);
```

Then you can write regular old Ruby to dynamically create the class

```
class_def = {name: "Foo", ivars: ["bar"], methods: ["baz"]}

klass = Class.new
klass.instance_eval do
  class_def[:ivars].each do |var|
    attr_accessor var
  end

  class_def[:methods].each do |meth|
    define_method(meth) do |*args|
      ivars = Hash[instance_variables.map { |name| [name, instance_variable_get(name)] }]
      MyAPI.call(class_def[:name], meth, ivars, args)
    end
  end
end

Kernel.const_set(class_def[:name], klass)

foo = Foo.new
f.bar = 5
f.baz("Hi") # MyAPI.call("Foo", "baz", {:@bar=>5}, ["Hi"])
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this part of the question:

```
And how can I know which Ruby method was called if each method uses the same dispatcher function?
```

You can do this will caller_locations, and you can accomplish that with rb_eval.  So essentially:

```
VALUE myMethodName = rb_eval("caller_locations(1,1).first.label");
```

This will tell your C function what method it was called at.  Note that we don't want caller_locations(0) because this is actually the eval() context which is back in the ruby code that called this method, and caller_locations(1) is the C method.